# Unexpected result for a type counter using templates with function local types in Clang

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, clang

I wrote a class template based on two types that is assigned a unique index based on its template parameters:

```
template<typename SK,typename T>
struct Component {
    static uint const index;
};
```

The expectation is that for each new type, `index` is incremented:

```
Component<X,A>::index; // 0
Component<X,B>::index; // 1

Component<Y,A>::index; // 0
Component<Y,B>::index; // 1
// ...etc
```

The complete code that assigns the indices is as follows:

```
using uint = unsigned int;

template<typename SK,typename T>
struct Component
{
    static uint const index;
};

template<typename SK>
class ComponentCount
{
    template<typename CSK,typename CT>
    friend struct Component;

private:
    template<typename T>
    static uint next() {
        return ComponentCount<SK>::get_counter();
    }

    static uint get_counter()
    {
        static uint counter = 0;
        return counter++;
    }
};
```

This works as expected in GCC (5.1) and MSVC with the following test:

```
// global scope
struct X {};
struct Y {};

int main()
{
    // function scope
    struct Z{};

    uint x0 = Component<X,int>::index;
    uint x1 = Component<X,double>::index;
    uint x2 = Component<X,double>::index;
    uint x3 = Component<X,std::string>::index;
    uint x4 = Component<X,int>::index;
    uint x5 = Component<X,int>::index;

    std::cout << x0 << ", " << x1 << ", " << x2 << ", "
              << x3 << ", " << x4 << ", " << x5 << std::endl;

    uint y0 = Component<Y,int>::index;
    uint y1 = Component<Y,double>::index;
    uint y2 = Component<Y,double>::index;
    uint y3 = Component<Y,std::string>::index;
    uint y4 = Component<Y,int>::index;
    uint y5 = Component<Y,int>::index;

    std::cout << y0 << ", " << y1 << ", " << y2 << ", "
              << y3 << ", " << y4 << ", " << y5 << std::endl;

    uint z0 = Component<Z,int>::index;
    uint z1 = Component<Z,double>::index;
    uint z2 = Component<Z,double>::index;
    uint z3 = Component<Z,std::string>::index;
    uint z4 = Component<Z,int>::index;
    uint z5 = Component<Z,int>::index;

    std::cout << z0 << ", " << z1 << ", " << z2 << ", "
              << z3 << ", " << z4 << ", " << z5 << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
0, 1, 1, 2, 0, 0
0, 1, 1, 2, 0, 0
0, 1, 1, 2, 0, 0
```

However with Clang (3.6.1), the output differs:

```
0, 1, 1, 2, 0, 0
0, 1, 1, 2, 0, 0
5, 2, 2, 3, 5, 5
```

Specifically, the indices generated for function local types (ie. 'Z') do something strange. Its like they increment and reassign the index every time `Component<Z,...>` is called.

Why does this happen? Is it a compiler bug? Are there any special considerations when using function local types with templates (post C++11)?

A complete example can be found here:
http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7fcb989ae6eab476

== Edit ==

I decided to post the issue to clang's bugtracker, so if anyone else runs into this:

https://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=24048

Comment: It looks like clang is expecting the initializing expression for `Component<SK, T>::index` to be pure. Removing the `const` specifier on `index` gives the [expected result](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bc8c910192a2ee67).

Comment: I am not entirely sure if this program is well-formed; maybe it is well-formed but the output is unspecified. For example, the different instantiations of the static data member should have unordered initialization. The order of initialization however determines the output of the program.

Comment: It is also unclear if the order of instantiations within the function is well-defined. However, I don't see any reason for the `5` or `3` to appear in the output (that would require UB I believe, and I don't see any UB here, only unspecified order). See also https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/d/msg/std-discussion/M6aJMH_ewoM/BpXj_heDGjMJ

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a bug to me. I am not aware of C++11 rules that should make a difference for function local types and global types.

If you [dump the assembler](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0fe52c1bb116c3a1), you can notice that while for `X` and `Y` the values get actually computed, for `Z` they are precomputed. The guard variables for the counter static variable initialization are not generated at all.

```
.Ltmp87:
    #DEBUG_VALUE: main:z5 <- 5
    #DEBUG_VALUE: main:z4 <- 5
    #DEBUG_VALUE: main:z3 <- 3
    #DEBUG_VALUE: main:z2 <- 2
    #DEBUG_VALUE: main:z1 <- 2
    #DEBUG_VALUE: main:z0 <- 5
    .loc    6 54 5                  # main.cpp:54:5
    movl    std::cout, %edi
    movl    $5, %esi
    .loc    6 74 5                  # main.cpp:74:5
    callq   std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >::operator<<(unsigned int)
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is a bug in clang, but it seems that you have an issue with your current version of Component::template next.

To show this, I changed the access to the function member from "private" to "public". Then with the following code:

```
for(int i=0; i<5;++i)
    std::cout<< ComponentCount<int>::next<int>() <<" ";
```

I get:

> 0 1 2 3 4

So maybe you should consider changing your implemention of next into something like this:

```
template<typename SK>
class ComponentCount
{
    template<typename CSK,typename CT>
    friend struct Component;

private:
    template<typename T>
    static uint next() {
        static uint index = get_counter();
        return index;
    }

    static uint get_counter()
    {
        static uint counter = 0;
        return counter++;
    }
};
```

With this I get the expected result on gcc, clang3.6 and VS2015

> g++ (GCC) 5.1.0 Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc. This
>   is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
>   warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR
>   PURPOSE.
>
> 0, 1, 1, 2, 0, 0
>
> 0, 1, 1, 2, 0, 0
>
> 0, 1, 1, 2, 0, 0
>
> clang version 3.6.0 (tags/RELEASE_360/final 235480) Target:
>   x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu Thread model: posix
>
> 0, 1, 1, 2, 0, 0
>
> 0, 1, 1, 2, 0, 0
>
> 0, 1, 1, 2, 0, 0

[final code + runs of gcc & clang on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ac4f5f1c4e0e7de8)

[edit] typos